# Watch request successful but not receiving any messages

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying to get Gmail push notifications by setting up a watch notification. I went through all the steps in the [Push Notification guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) and received a successful  historyId/expiration response, but since then all's quiet. I haven't gotten any of the emails pushed through. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, your application will only receive a notification message describing the change if the mailbox update matches your watch request.

With this, try to provide the topic name and any other options in your `watch()` request, such as [`labels`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels) to filter on. For example, to be notified any time a change is made to the Inbox:

```
POST "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/watch"
Content-type: application/json

{
  topicName: "projects/myproject/topics/mytopic",
  labelIds: ["INBOX"],
}
```

Other than that, check your [Gmail notifications settings](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1075549). If that still doesn’t work, try the troubleshooting steps given [here](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2650727).